# Joomla 'component not found' install error

Tags: joomla, components, http-status-code-404

I made a component that was working find on my local machine but when I tried to put it on live site it gives me '404 - An error has occurred. Component not found' error that doesn't seem to go away. I have tried everything from installing from different admins to putting the files directly to server but nothing works. I even tried installing it on another joomla site but that doesn't help either. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck on this since morning and finally got the solution. This might be of help... 
The component name was com_ABCdef and it worked on local like that however when I installed in to site it became all small letters and was calling for option=com_abcdef and my installation files file ABCdef.xml and ABCdef.php and changing those to lower case solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

how are you doing it ?

- Do you have the xml install file ?
- name convention? i think name should always be com_componentName
- have you placed it in the component directory ?

read more about joomla component here http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

Comment: Yea I had everything .. I have been working on joomla for a while now.. I found out the error after about 30min of posting but it wouldn't let me post then.. let me post it now.